# Framework for Custom Swipe To Go Back (Twitter Like)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, custom-transition

I'd like to implement a custom `UINavigationController` pop transition. The interactive swipe to go back similar to what Twitter on iOS is doing.

For some technical reasons (beyond the scope of the question), I cannot use the default behavior of the `UINavigationController`.

It doesn't matter the language Swift or Objective-c.

Comment: Please check: https://github.com/kingiol/KDInteractiveNavigationController

Comment: Unfortunately will not work, because I need a custom transition. But this one uses the system transition.